# how to know whether an entry into database is unique or not

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have a table consisting of two columns url and the html code of that url. the column names used are url_in and html_code. I enter the data's into the table using PHP mysql. Now my problem is that i want to create a function that as soon as we enter the url i want that function to check if the url is already existing in table or no, if it is present then the code should echo url already added or else it should add the url to the database.

Comment: I answered a question earlier that is almost exactly the same. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27348719/how-to-avoid-inserting-a-duplicate-value

Comment: but i want it in php manner

Comment: Why don't you let your database handle this?  It's ***far*** better at doing this, and it would be portable; if your application moved away from PHP, then your database would still enforce the unique constraints.

Comment: I agree whole heartedly with @Makoto which is the answer I gave in the other question.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code.

```
function check_unique($url){
      $sql = "select * from table_name where url_in = '$url'";
      $result = mysql_query($sql); //use mysqli instead of mysql. Here I use mysql for example
      if(mysql_num_rows($result)===0){
            return true;
      }else{
            return false;
      }
}
```

Now you check with this function for example

```
$url = "http://www.google.com";

//check unique
$isUnique = check_unique($url);

if($isUnique){
     //do insert query
}else{
     echo 'URL already exist';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
INSERT INTO table(url_in , html_code)
  SELECT 'YOUR_URL','YOUR HTML CODE' FROM DUAL
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
  (SELECT url_in  FROM table WHERE url_in ='YOUR_URL');
```